# Tool for batch editing code generator files

Tags: windows, editing

I have around 60 php files that are generated by a code generator, and after each requirement modification the files need to be changed (replace text, file rename). Can you recommend a Windows tool that can save the changes I need to make and automatically do them each time the source files are changed?

Comment: A simply python script might work for that...what are the exact requirements?

Comment: The changes are usually text replacement for elements of code (layout, method calls) but there are many things that are done over and over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

It allows you to create change/substitution lists in a file, then run those changes against the files you are working on.

There is a small learning curve, but within 15/20 minutes you should be making progress.